# Web.confg issue multiple user accessing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web, web-config

This is causing the issue when multiple user access the web.config file at the same time
the error says the file is  being used by another process

```cs
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(string.Empty);

var section = config.GetSection(configSectionName);

// If the section exists and it is not protected
if (section != null && !section.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
{
    // Get the name of the default provider
       
    var pcs = (ProtectedConfigurationSection)config.GetSection("configProtectedData");
    var provider = pcs.DefaultProvider;

    // Apply the provider to the section and save
                    
    section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection(provider);
    config.Save();
}
```

Comment: first of all, avoid to write and save on web.config -  because is makes the full project to re-compile each time you do that - the solution if you continue with this function is to use Mutex to lock each read/write - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.mutex?view=net-5.0

Comment: You can and should be able to read + use the config file with multiple users. But you NEVER EVER want to update the web.config file. If web config is modifed, then the application pool will detect this and re-start. It detects this change and causes a web re-start since there can be 100's if not 1000's of things that might have change in the config file, and thus the application pools will automatic re-start to see and get all the possible 100's if not more changes. A change to web config should NEVER EVER in ANY case EVER occur during runtime.